# Heater/Light/Vent switch question

Tags: electrical, switch

I'm a homeowner. I had an electrician install the rough-in and I'm installing the outlets/switches/lights etc myself.

Bathroom has a H/L/V and the electrician wired the switch so I could use 3 regular switches instead of buying the costly one that has 3 on 1.

I have two "normal" switches (2 black wires 1 green).

The third switch has one white, one black, and one green. 
I can't find any information about where the white wire goes.

Any clues? Do I treat it as a black wire?

The power company just hooked the power up last week but I haven't turned the breakers on yet so I'm not sure if any voltage is flowing to the white wire.

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: I think this is a labeling issue between different manufactures.  I'd prefer the white/black labeling, as it tells me which wire is always hot, and which one is switched hot.  But there is no functional difference.

Comment: Thank you Chris. This is for the switch, not the appliance. It's wired with 2/12 wire and the electrician twisted all the wires that go together, capped off the others. One bundle has a black, a white, and a green (copper) wire. I've never seen a light switch with a white wire on it.

Comment: Can you post a picture?  I can edit it in to your question if you like.

Comment: A picture is needed. Assuming this is new work, by code there should be a neutral supplied to the switch box (even if you don't currently need it). If there is really only one neutral then it's probably just to meet code and might not be needed. Typically there would be a supply cable (with black always-hot and white wires) and some cables to the fixture with switched hots and a bunch of white neutrals all connected. There may also be some variants, especially if the heater is 240V. Post some pictures and information on the fixture.